# Запросы Linq для двух коллекций

Tags: c#, linq

Есть два класса:

```
class Employees
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

и

```
class Salaryes
{
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Созданы две коллекции `List<>`. Помогите пожалуйста сделать Linq-выборку для определения отдела с максимальной средней зарплатой

```
var maxAverageQuery = listEmployees.GroupBy(list => list.Department).Select(gr => new { gr.Key, Sum = listSalaryes.Where(list2=>listEmployees.Select(list=>list.Position).ToString()==list2.Position).Average(lis => lis.Salary) })
```

Comment: А можете описать ваши классы, как они взаимодействуют друг с другом, какое значение общее? А также хотелось бы увидеть исходный результат (то, что в итоге должны получить).

Comment: EvgeniyZ общее поле в двух классах position , должны получить название отдела с максимальной средней зарплатой

Comment: Вы по странному реализовали связь. По хорошему ваш класс `Salaryes` должен называться `Position` и иметь свойства вроде `Name` и `Value`, а `Employees` должен иметь свойство `Position` типа не `string`, а этого `Position`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
var employees = new List<Employees>(...);
var salaryes = new List<Salaryes>(...);
var ExpensiveDepartment = employees
    // Соединяем сотрудников и позиции,
    //  выбираем в итоговую выборку наименование отдела и зарплату сотрудника
    .Join(salaryes, e => e.Position, s => s.Position, (e, s) => new { e.Department, s.Salary })
    // Группируем по отделам
    .GroupBy(a => a.Department, a => a.Salary)
    // Находим для каждого отдела среднюю зарплату
    .Select(g => new { Department = g.Key, AvgSalary = g.Average() })
    // Сортируем по средней зарплате
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.AvgSalary)
    // Берем самое большое значение средней зарплаты
    .First()
    // Берем наименование отдела
    .Department;
```

Но на самом деле вы как-то странно организовали иерархию классов, во-первых, почему названия классов во множественном числе? Это ведь один экземпляр (если у вас EF или типа того, не переживайте, он сам разберется как ему именовать таблицы), во-вторых, почему бы не хранить в сотруднике ссылку на его должность? Итого:

```
class Employee
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Position
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

И потом всё становится несколько проще:

```
var employees = new List<Employee>(...);
var salaryes = new List<Position>(...);
var ExpensiveDepartment = employees
    .GroupBy(e => e.Department)
    .Select(g => new { Department = g.Key, AvgSalary = g.Average(e => e.Position.Salary) })
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.AvgSalary)
    .First()
    .Department;
```

Comment: Андрей NOP,спасибо